# How to connect via twitter api using OAuth

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I am trying to make an web application that should tweet on users account. I am using this api https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth and for now I managed to post a tweet on my account using access tokens.

```
$twitterConnection = new TwitterOAuth(
                    'XXXX', // Consumer Key
                    'XXXX',     // Consumer secret
                    'XXXX',       // Access token
                    'XXXX'      // Access token secret
                    );



$content =  $twitterConnection->get('account/verify_credentials');

$twitterConnection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "First tweet via API"));
echo  $twitterConnection->http_code;
```

But when I try to use examples given there to allow application to access someone's account I receive 401 ERROR in redirect.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up this access level in the twitter api control panel?

Comment: I set up Read and Write access level to post and get tweets. Is there something else to set up?

Comment: Add a callback URL in the Twitter control panel. 401 is the code for unauthorized.